# MIMIC-II query builder unavailable for running query on waveform table

Tags: mimic-iii

I am trying to run a query on MIMIC-II database but it currently has an invalid certificate (SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN) and browsers refuse to go there:

https://mimic2app.csail.mit.edu/querybuilder/

Is there any alternative way to access it?

Specifically I am interested to run a query that selects all users containing specific waveform types such as II.

Is there a way to do it on MIMIC-III if the MIMIC-II database is no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted the physionet webmaster telling them that they have a bad certificate. They have fixed it promptly, the MIMIC-II [query builder](https://mimic2app.csail.mit.edu/querybuilder/) is available again.